# Update From clause in SQL Server CE doesn't work , any Solutions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I've this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Movement_Item_Lots 
SET Batch_Code = (SELECT WHSS.Batch_Code 
                  FROM WH_Stock_Serials AS WHSS 
                  WHERE WHSS.Item_Code = Movement_Item_Lots.Item_Code 
                  AND   WHSS.From_Distribution_Code = Movement_Item_Lots.Distribution_Code 
                 )
```

it returns :

> There was an error parsing the query.
>   [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 19,Token in error = SELECT ]

I know this is common issue in SQL Server CE that it can't do update from, any workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Change to sqlite, if possible, this sql would work... If not possible, you can always divide the statement in your program:

1. var <- SELECT WHSS.Batch_Code...
2. UPDATE .. SET Batch_Code = var